# python pip install gives ssl Certificate error

Tags: python, pip

I am getting a SSSL certificate error: I tried `--trusted-host` and all other options I can find in while googling but I cant figure out why I get the error.

I get the error when I run as other user beside **root**.

```
(vmware) [user@machine vmware]$ pip3 install --upgrade pip --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./lib/python3.6/site-packages (21.3.1)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:877)'),)': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:877)'),)': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:877)'),)': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:877)'),)': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:877)'),)': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:877)'),)) - skipping
```

but when I run the same command as root, I dont get an error.

```
(vmware) [user@machine vmware]$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/6d/6463d49a933f547439d6b5b98b46af8742cc03ae83543e4d7688c2420f8b/pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.7MB 11.6MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-21.3.1
```

Comment: And is your "user" Pip now up to date?

Comment: Are both `pip3` executables the same, in fact? `pip3 --version` and `sudo pip3 --version`, for example.

Comment: @kwinkunks Is that a Windows thing, given the name? `sudo` isn't a Windows things, afaik.

Comment: @9769953
 (vmware) [user@machinevmware]$ pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from /home/pqt1109a/Environments/vmware/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

it did update because I ran it as a root. 

kwinkunks - its a Linux machine so i dont think python-certifi-win32 will work!!

Comment: Python 3.6 is old, and not supported anymore. You should look into upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

idk what the full issue was, but what I did to fix it, I created a pip.conf on my home directly with trusted host variables and its values as above. Then logged out and logged back in to source it again and it started working. Thank to all who helped, much appreciated.